# Get the supported "bitness" of an x86 CPU when booted in 16-bit mode

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I am developing an x86 bootloader and have come across this problem (which I guess should be pretty straightforward, but so far I haven't been able to solve): I want to detect the bitness of the CPU host (e.g. if it's 16bit-only, or supports 32bit or 64bit).

I have used the CPUID instruction, but it was introduced with 486 so doesn't help for detecting 16-bit-only vs. a 386-compatible CPU that supports 32-bit protected mode (or 32-bit operand-size in real mode with prefixes).

Comment: Just out of curiosity - what will you be booting, that supports all of 16, 32 and 64-bit processors?

Comment: How are you developing this bootloader? If you are writing assembly for a specific CPU, than that CPU is the CPU on which the code will run. If it's a 16 bit CPU and has no other operating modes, then it's a 16 bit CPU - it's "bitness" is 16.

Comment: (Putting it another way: are you trying to determine at run time something that it seems like you could probably know at compile time?)

Comment: Related: If you want to know what mode you're *currently* in, [this 11 byte polyglot function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/139243/determine-your-languages-version/139717#139717) returns 16, 32, or 64 (in `AL`) depending on the mode it's executed in.  But you want to detect (from booting in 16-bit mode) and detect if the CPU supports switching to 32 and 64, which isn't the same thing.

Comment: @xs0, it's a just-for-curiosity project I am trying to build: a kernel which will (try to) support 16, 32 and 64 bits :)  -- I know at some point it will become insane.

Comment: @davmac: A BIOS booting in legacy non-EFI mode loads the boot-sector and jumps to it in 16-bit real mode.  It's up to that code to switch to protected or long mode (after loading more sectors or whatever).  If you want to print a nice error message on (virtual) machines that don't support 32 or 64 bit modes, you need to check first.  e.g. with http://wiki.osdev.org/Setting_Up_Long_Mode#Detecting_the_Presence_of_Long_Mode

Comment: @davmac, yes, I am tring to get that info at runtime

Comment: @xs0: uh, x86 obviously.  Every modern x86 CPU supports all 3 modes; it's still required to have HW support for 16-bit real mode.  It's not weird to check and print an error if 32 or especially 64-bit isn't supported, before trying to switch to it.  (It would be a bit odd to have a fat binary for a kernel that fully worked in the highest mode available, though.)

Comment: @PeterCordes well yes, but I was inquiring about the software, not the hardware :)

Comment: @xs0: Oh, I see what you meant.  As I commended to davmac, legacy BIOS booting starts in real mode, so if you want your bootloader to print an error on HW that doesn't support 32 bit or 64 bit mode, you should detect first.  It's actually tricky for an OS kernel or bootloader to enter long mode directly from 16-bit mode, so it's totally normal to go 16 -> 32 -> 64.

Comment: @PeterCordes hence "has no other operating modes". It wasn't clear if the question was about x86 only... (or was it? I see the tags now. Maybe I missed them earlier; my bad if so).

Comment: I recall this question being asked quite often. This has to be a duplicate.  You can find out if your CPU is a 386 or better by checking some bits in FLAGS.

Comment: @AntónSeoane: Detecting support for 64-bit mode is shown in detail on the OSdev wiki.  http://wiki.osdev.org/Setting_Up_Long_Mode#Detecting_the_Presence_of_Long_Mode.  The Protected Mode article (http://wiki.osdev.org/Protected_Mode)  doesn't have a detection method shown.  It has links to more stuff.  I'm not going to post an answer; I'll leave that for one of the people that like to play with custom kernels.

Comment: This [page](http://www.rcollins.org/ddj/Sep96/Sep96.html) has code to detect pre CPUID CPUs. If you have the CPUID instruction, you can use it to detect 64-bit mode (32-bit is implied).

Comment: @davmac: The title and text are a bit generic, but it is tagged `[x86]` and hasn't been edited.  If you miss the tags it certainly looks like it's including purely 16-bit CPUs, though.  (Anton, you might want to put x86 into the text somewhere; there are non-x86 CPUs in the world, and tags aren't what everyone reads first).

Comment: @MargaretBloom: Ah, that's the piece I didn't find on OSdev.  They show how to detect >= 386 by seeing it clear bits 12-15 in FLAGS after you try to set them with popf.

Comment: @PeterCordes, thanks a lot! (btw, title is changed now :) )

Comment: @MargaretBloom, thanks, a pretty useful article!!

Comment: Unless you have a real computer with an 8088, 8086 or 80268 CPU I wouldn't worry about supporting 16-bits. Without a real computer to test on you'll never know if it really works. Running your code under a more modern computer, or even an emulator, won't be a good test because more modern computers support things in 16-bit mode that the older 16-bit only computers didn't. Also most bootloaders that require '386 or newer CPU don't check for CPU support, they just crash if run on an older CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking for 32-bits (see http://www.rcollins.org/ddj/Sep96/Sep96.html):

- 16-bit CPUs without protected mode (8088/8086/80186) will always have the upper 4 bits (15-12) of the flags register set when doing `pushf`
- 80286 will always have the upper 4 bits clear on `pushf` (when running in real mode)
- CPUs supporting 32-bit allow modifying the upper 4 bits in real mode using `popf` (however all 4 bits should have the same value - all set or all clear)

By using `pushf`, `popf` and modifying the data on the stack you check if it is possible to modify the upper 4 bits; if yes, it must be a 32-bit CPU.

Checking for `CPUID`:

- Ensure the CPU supports 32-bit (see above)
- Switch to 32-bits mode
- Check if bit 21 of EFLAGS can be modified (set and cleared); if the value of that bit is not fixed (it can be changed from 0 to 1 or vice versa) the `cpuid` instruction is supported.